# React application throwing error in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and installed visual studio code to run my `react`. I also installed `create-react-app` generator to create a sample application. Once I create hello world application and say npm start in my command prompt, the browser appear with `localhost://3000` but no text or image being displayed, it is just blank page. When I run the same code through VS code with debugging option, it says the following error in debug console.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=18639 helloworldapp\src\App.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:18639/02076770-342f-4cc0-be83-163c31c2668d
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
import React from 'react';
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: can you show your App.js ?

Comment: Note: I am using Microsoft windows 10 and didn't modify any code..just created hello app using create-app-generator

Comment: import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: Is there any error message in the browser console?

Comment: just simply run the code without debugging option and see browser console for any errors